# Placing a background picture and then having invisible touch (Android)

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application for android that is based on IPAD app. I want to keep the same look to the app, but I am not a very good designer. So I was wondering if it was possible to for me to crop say the entire header and then have an invisible button or something on top of portions of it. so the design would become a little bit easier. Also if that is possible how would I get the what ever the event item is going to be to overlap with a portion of the image if it has stranger orientation. (I think I could fake this by just moving it closest orientation and extending the size untill it fits, but it would be nice to find a better way.)

How would I go about that?

I tried making the button invisible, but that did not seem to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got lost on your description. But if you want to make a button invisible, calling `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` will **not** work, because it will not receive click events. You may want to set its color to transparent instead. try using:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```